# Using libspotify .dll/.lib files in MinGW32 compiling pySpotify

Tags: python, c, spotify, cpython

Using `MinGW32` on a Windows PC I am trying to compile [pySpotify](http://pyspotify.mopidy.com/). The first error was that `libspotify/api.h` was missing. I *fixed* this by copying the appropriate folder from [libspotify](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/#download) into `C:\MinGW\include`. However now `dllwrap` is now failing with `ld linking.` The binaries `Spotify` distribute are `libspotify.dll` and `libspotify.lib.` No matter where I put them *(pySpotify folder/subfolders, temp build folder/subfolders and MinGW folder/subfolders)* or what I name them *(.a, .o & .so)* it **still shows the same error messages.**

The pertinent error is:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\dllwrap.exe -mdll -static --output-lib build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lib_spotify.a --def build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\_spotify.def -s build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\module.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\session.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\link.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\track.obuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\album.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\albumbrowser.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\artist.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\artistbrowser.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\search.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\playlist.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\playlistcontainer.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\playlistfolder.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\image.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\user.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\pyspotify.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\toplistbrowser.o -LC:\Python26\libs -LC:\Python26\PCbuild -lspotify -lpython26 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win32-2.7\spotify\_spotify.pyd
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lspotify
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
dllwrap: gcc exited with status 1
error: command 'dllwrap' failed with exit status 1
```

[bok says on github](https://github.com/mopidy/pyspotify/issues/63) that:

> You need to add the API headers in the include path (add something like -I~\libspotify\include to your compiler options) and the shared library in the library path (add -L~\libspotify\lib to your linker options). This will allow the compiler to find the necessary include files, and your linker to find the necessary binary objects.

However the `distutils` Extension class seems to be deprecated and hard to find documentation for (I believe this is where custom compiler options need to go). Appreciate that `~` may need changed to `%USERPROFILE%` or similar. Similarly `%PYTHONPATH%\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg` has little documentation beyond the `[build]` `compiler=mingw32` stanza. This makes editing the compile/link commands and their options impossible to change.

**How do you compile pySpotify on Windows?**

**EDIT:**

By using Python 2.6 and copying libspotify.dll/libspotify.lib to C:\Python26\PCbuild and renaming them to spotify.dll/libspotify.lib I now receive another error message from ld:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\dllwrap.exe -mdll -static --output-lib build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\src\lib_spotify.a --def build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\src\_spotify.def -s build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\src\module.o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\src\session.o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\src\link.o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\src\track.obuild\temp.win32-2.6\Release\src\album.o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\src\albumbrowser.o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\src\artist.o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\src\artistbrowser.o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\src\search.o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\src\playlist.o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\src\playlistcontainer.o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\src\playlistfolder.o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\src\image.o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\src\user.o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\src\pyspotify.o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\src\toplistbrowser.o -LC:\Python26\libs -LC:\Python26\PCbuild -lspotify -lpython26 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win32-2.6\spotify\_spotify.pyd
_spotify.exp: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
dllwrap: gcc exited with status 1
error: command 'dllwrap' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Perhaps the absolute path isn't read correctly by mingw's ld? That is, try moving libspotify to a relative location and see if that doesn't help.

Comment: Hi Nik, thanks for the suggestion - but I've tried copying to every folder/subfolder I can find to no avail: "No matter where I put them (pySpotify folder/subfolders, temp build folder/subfolders and MinGW folder/subfolders)."

Answer (score 1):

Not having access to a mingw installation at the moment, I can suggest a few things.

First, `ld` is known to be picky about order of arguments. Strangely, when I googled for "ld argument order", I got a bunch of pages suggesting that the order doesn't matter, but I have been burned several times by this. I've had the most success with the following argument order:

1. Switches to `ld` (ie, `-Wall`)
2. Library search paths (ie, `-LPATH`)
3. Object files
4. Libraries (ie, `-lspotify`)

I noticed in your linker output some references to amd64. I'm not sure how you compiled the other object files that you have, but since libspotify is 32-bit on Windows, I'm guessing that mixing 32/64 bit here is not going to work out too well.

The last thing I can think of is that perhaps the dll extension is confusing to `ld`, have you tried changing the filename to `libspotify.so`? I know this is kind of a shot in the dark, but otherwise I'm not sure how to help you further.

Comment: I've tried renaming both files to .so, .a and .o. When I tried using MinGW64 it complained it couldn't compile, so I am now using MinGW instead (on 64-bit Windows). With the build script I have no access to argument ordering which is part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to link a 64bit version of pyspotify against a 32bit version of libspotify. Try to rebuild pyspotify adding the -m32 to CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS

Comment: I do not know how to access the CFLAG/CXXFLAGS with setup.py (the build script for pySpotify).

Comment: CFLAGS=-m32 python setup.py should do the trick. Also make sure you have installed a 32bit python. Please notice that the problem may well be reversed: maybe pyspotify was compiled in 32bit and libspotify is 64bit.

Comment: `'CFLAGS' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` is the error you receive on Windows (know this works on *nix). Am going to play around with environment variables and check python is 32 bit.

Comment: Now the build path is build\temp.win32-2.6 (using 32-bit Python 2.6) but still no luck (dllwrap again).

Comment: Everything is 32-bit now apart from Windows itself (updated the error message in the question to reflect this). Tried adding -m32 to the CFLAGS environment variable and saw no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I've added some instructions on how I got it to compile on the actual ticket for the issue. Let me Know if it helped you!

https://github.com/mopidy/pyspotify/issues/63

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: I just made an account and the max amount of links I could post were two. I had several links in the solution, so therefore I figured the best way to have all of the information intact was to post a link to the actual ticket were I posted my solution.

Comment: the point is to post the _solution here_ (vs. posting a link to a solution elsewhere :-)